# What is the angular2 event for pressing 'Enter'

Tags: angular

I have a refresh icon that is accessible (can be reached by tabbing), but the event trigger to refresh is `(click)`, but this is not triggered when the focus is on the icon and enter is pressed. What is the event trigger for that called?

Code:

```
<span (click)="refresh()" tabindex="0" role="button"></span>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
(keyup.enter)="somefunction()"
```

this is the event for enter

Comment: try it and give me feedback

Comment: I tried `(keydown.enter)` instead, but it works! Thanks :)

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
(keydown)="someFun()"
```

Ex:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userName" (keydown)="userNameEntered()">
```